# Finding roots of cubing equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all roots of the following polynomial:

$$x^3 + x^2 + 1$$

Comment: What level of math are you studying?

Comment: You can use cardon's method to find roots.

Comment: @ Satvik Mashkaria. How?

Comment: See [cubic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Use [Cardano's Method](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/polynomials/cubicAlgebra.htm#2%20Equation%20in%20p%20and%20q%20where%20neither%20zero). It's easy, trust me! (>‿◠)✌

Comment: ooh Full answer thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formulas of Cardano equation but not for sheep, because the form of the equation which is elected by the Cardano formulas is:
$$x^3+px+q=0$$

If the equation is of the form:
$$x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$$
Your equation is the form of the above, therefore, by means of substitution $$x+\frac{a}{3}=y$$
acquired forms:
$$y^3+\alpha y +\delta=0$$
where 
$$\alpha=-3\left(\frac{a}{3}\right)^2+b; \beta=-\left(\frac{a}{3}\right)^3+c; \delta=-\alpha\frac{a}{3}+\beta$$
i.e
You should be solving the equation:
$$27y^3-9y+2=0$$
using formulas of Cardano